# How to store array of smallint in DB2

Tags: db2, datastore

I need to keep indefinite number of smallints in a column. 
This column may keep only one or few numbers as in [1], [2,100] or up to a couple thousand numbers.
My first thought was keeping them varchar with comma seperation but that makes column too large (even over limit i believe). 
Then i think i coul use clob, but this also not a good choice in my opinion since my real data is not string but numbers
Now, i am aware that it might be better normalize this and keep them in seperate rows, but i want to know if there is an effective way to do it so i can evaluate my choices.
I did try to search this but couldnt find anything fulfills my need. 
Thanks for help in advance

Comment: What are you planning on doing with such an array?  If you're planning on searching or updating in the db, it's probably going to be easiest if you normalize and store it.  (On the other hand, it'd probably need about twice the disk space, given you'd need a key column for such a thing).  What version of DB2?  Some of them have array types, although I don't think you can actually use them as columns (just variables in stored procedures and stuff).

Comment: As far as I can see, the only reason to store data like this is because you want it reported that way.  But you can store that data normally and pivot it when you need to display it like that.  Store it normalized in separate rows.

Comment: Thanks for input. This data is not for reporting but for a one-time use. When job is done (started from another source that inserted data) its pretty much done and will be a report data only if needed. <br> We have 9.something version of DB2, not really sure which version if thats enough.<br> Did a bit more thinking and seperating data is actually a better way to do it. Still i would like to learn if thats possible to do